# Should I cancel the key when SocketChannel#connect returns true?

Tags: java, nio, socketchannel

When `SocketChannel#connect` returns a `true` for a selector-registered `SocketChannel`, should I cancel the `SelectionKey`?

```java
                final var client = SocketChannel.open();
                client.configureBlocking(false);
                final var key = client.register(selector, OP_CONNECT);

                if (client.connect(endpoint)) { // connected, immediately
                    key.cancel(); // Should I do this?
                    ...
                }
```

Comment: No, but you should deregister for the `OP_CONNECT` event, via `key.interestOps(key.interestOps() & ~OP_CONNECT);` You are certainly going to want to register this channel later for `OP_READ`, and at suitable times for `OP_WRITE`.

Comment: @user207421 Wonderful! You might wanna spend some minutes to put your comment as an answer. Thank you.